# Installing PHP 5.4 on CentOS 6

Tags: ssh, centos, php, yum, centos-6

I want to update my CentOS 6 PHP version from 5.3 to 5.4 so I tried this guide: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php54/

But after running `yum install php54w` I get this:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package php54w available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I've tried to reinstall http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm many times, but it didn't seem to help...

Tips, anyone?

Comment: Have you seen these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11361068/install-php-5-4-1-in-centos6-2, http://serverfault.com/questions/425841/how-to-install-php-devel-under-centos-6-3-x64

Comment: @techie007 Thanks for your reponse. I actually saw them before and they didn't really help me...

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `/etc/yum.conf` has `php-*` excluded in it... Removed it and it's now solved.